# Collection or list for SPUser and SPGroup objects?

Tags: groups, user

I would like to store in c# code some list or collection or what else to store SPUser and SPGroup objects. After this I would like to do some foreach loop and do some logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
List<SPPrincipal> usersAndGroups = new List<SPPrincipal>();
```

Comment: If you're happy with this as a solution, please can you mark this post as the answer.  It'll help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understand your question correctly, but if you need to get some users and make foreach loop (and do some logic) on them on the same time when they were fetched and they will not be used later, you definetely need to use collection for it. If you need results of some logic later, you can save them to a list.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a [blog post I found](http://chrissyblanco.blogspot.com/2007/07/determining-whether-user-is-member-of.html), I have written the following code:

```
private static List<SPUser> ListUsers(SPWeb web, SPPrincipal group)
{
    try
    {
        web.Site.CatchAccessDeniedException = false;
        var users = new List<SPUser>();
        foreach(SPUser user in web.SiteUsers)
        {
            using(var userContextSite = new SPSite(web.Site.ID, user.UserToken))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var userContextWeb = userContextSite.OpenWeb(web.ID))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (userContextWeb.SiteGroups[group.Name]
                                .ContainsCurrentUser)
                                    users.Add(user);
                        }
                        catch (SPException)
                        {
                            // group not found, continue
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                    // user does not have right to open this web, continue
                }
            }
        }
        return users;
    }
    finally
    {
        web.Site.CatchAccessDeniedException = true;
    }
}
```

I don't like the fact that I have to impersonate every single user, and this code will only find AD users that have already been imported into SharePoint (so an `SPUser` exists for them), but that's good enough for me.

[Above answer has been copied from this Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466929/how-can-i-list-all-spuser-objects-in-a-spgroup) :